# How to run multiple cucumber runners from maven command line

Tags: maven, cucumber, runner

I've 2 CI flows , which flow needs to run it's own cucumber runner
RunnerATest
RunnerBTest

I'm using maven command line to run the tests (mvn test)

Is there a way to select a specific Runner from command line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> [Maven Surefire Plugin - Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)
>
> During development, you may run a single test class repeatedly. To run this through Maven, set the test property to a specific test case.
>
> `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test`

So you'd do just that. `mvn -Dtest=RunnerATest test`.

Comment: I receive a compilation error like *TestRunnerSC.java:[10,8] class TestRunner is public, should be declared in a file named TestRunner.java*